# c# Port forwarding example

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, portforwarding

So basically I have an URL blacklist, and in my project, i would need to use c# to listen to port 80 and redirect any request to those URLs to 127.0.0.1.

I don't know much about networking.I've seen some topics on SO but don't quite understand them.  An example of it would be nice. Some explanation that comes along would even be better.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your subject indicates you want port forwarding.  Port forwarding has nothing to do with URLs-- and would require understanding TCP/IP very well to implement, but it wouldn't "redirect" URLs.

Your description indicates you want to listen on port 80 and redirect requests to bad URLs.  This means you need to first implement an DNS server that will redirect that bad URLs to your port 80, implement an HTTP server, examine the host headers to determine what was really requested by the client, check your black list, and then form an http response to tell the client to redirect, but then somehow have your poisoned DNS server not send that request to you again.

I suspect what you really want is just a DNS server, or put your bad URLs in your hosts file and point them all to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Sorry it's a lot of information for me. My friend told me i can use TCPListener to listen at port 80, then unwrap the headers, if it is a request to one of my blacked URL, then resend the packet to somewhere else.Just wondering if it's a possible way to do it

Comment: I already implement the feature to change hosts file but it's too easy for people to edit

Comment: So that sounds like port fowarding based on inspection of the traffic.  You will need to do some very advanced stuff to do that.  You would have to spoof the client with a TCP handshaking long enough to get the http headers, then rewind and replay that traffic to the forwarded server just exactly right so the client didn't know you forwarded it.  There's no way to describe how much work that will be in a stack-overflow comment.

Comment: thank you for the information. I will try to look for other methods lol